# Node JS Async/Await strange output

Tags: node.js

I am not very familiar with Node JS, when I try with this code to test my understanding with Async/Await, I don't know why the out put of the following code is strange. Please help to explain:

```js
function timeHandler() {
  console.log('Timer');
}
async function f() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(timeHandler, 1000));
  console.log('f');
}

async function f2() {
  console.log('f2');
}

async function test() {
  await f();
  await f2();
}

test();
```

Ouput is:

```
Timer
```

Why it does not 'f' and 'f2'?

Comment: `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(timeHandler, 1000));` You never `resolve`.

Answer (score 2):

In this example you are not calling '`resolve`' after the promise is done, instead you are calling `timeHandler`. For that reason you can see the 'Timer'. If you want to resolve a promise, you must to call the resolve method after the timeout like this:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('resolved');
  }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function timeHandler() {
  console.log('Timer');
}
async function f() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => (timeHandler(), resolve()), 1000));
  console.log('f');
}

async function f2() {
  console.log('f2');
}

async function test() {
  await f();
  await f2();
}

test();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.